# How to edit the default user model provided by Strapi?

Tags: strapi

By default, strapi uses email password auth, because of which email and password are required fields. I want to have just email OTP auth. So I removed the password field from the attributes in `src/extensions/users-permissions/content-types/user/schema.json`.

When I try to create an entry in the user table from the admin console, I get an error saying `Password is a required field`. Why is this showing when I got rid of the password attribute? Is there some other file I need to make changes to?